# flex mobile change server to be public

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, wamp

Am developing mobile application which is connected to localhost server ( using WAMP php server) in my computer

program run smoothly on the flex debugger, but it dosnt to connect  database if i run through usb ,it just show program interface with no data, since its not connected to the server.

how can i change the server to be public so that it can be access from any mobile that have the application .

i have tried to change localhost to my network real ip address by port forwarding  but it didn't work correctly each time it takes me to the router page i don't know what i did wrong .

Answer (score 0):

[Localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), by definition, is a 'loopback' address; which will point to the machine in question.  I assume that when running an application on a device, 'localhost' will refer back to that device; which probably does not have your server software running on it.

I suggest you move your server to a place that is remotely accessible.  This could be something on your network, which is found via a local DNS server.  Or it could be something on a remote, production server.

Many domain registars, such as GoDaddy.com, offer DNS Service.  I use this to point "mydomain.com" to a production server, and "developer.mydomain.com" to a server on my local network.  You'll need static IPs on your 'developer network' for this to work, though.